# is there any tool or script to export a single record from a MySQL database and all of the records references / foreign constraints?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, database-administration

Is there any tool or script or simple way (without writing a custom script) that will export a single record from a table and all of it's references?

i.e. say i have a Users table and i want to export user where id = 1, and then the tool/script will look at what tables reference Users.id, and export the ones that reference userID = 1. So say An Addresses table has userID = 1, it would export that Address. And if anything referenced that Address for userID = 1, it would export that as well, and just keep recursively doing this.

It definitely seems possible with some SQL script by using the information_schema db, doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'Users' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'id' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database';
```

And then look at the results of that query and look through all those Tables, and then re-running the same query for each Table, and so on. Then selecting from the specified table based on an ID.

Just wondering if there's something out there that already does this?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for exactly this also. And to complement this a (simple) way to import without ID collisions in another DB.